# Boolean ftp_home_dir is not defined - RHEL7.3

Tags: selinux, vsftpd, rhel7

I'm trying to configure vsftpd 3.0.2 on RHEL 7.3. I am trying to set my `setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1` to enable users access to their home dir. However I receive:

```
Boolean ftp_home_dir is not defined
```

This is confirmed when viewing `semanage boolean -l` there is no `ftp_home_dir`.

Lines 14,15 & 16 state to check for this boolean in `vsftpd.conf`.

```
 # Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
 # When SELinux is enforcing check for SE bool ftp_home_dir
 local_enable=YES

/data/ftp/pub/some-dir/ftpuser1...etc
[root@xxxxx ftp]# ls -lZ
drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:etc_runtime_t:s0 pub
```

I am lead to believe that in fixing this, it will also fix my chroot issue I am having which is an entirely separate question.

Thanks in advance!

info:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
uname -a shows: 3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 16 13:15:13 EST 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

(Keep in mind we perform patching on a bi monthly system so updating is not an option currently).

Comment: I see this boolean in RHEL 6, but not in RHEL 7. I suggest you open a case with Red Hat. It might have been renamed or inadvertently omitted.

Comment: Thank you, I've gone ahead and opened a support case with them to see what they have to say. Looking directly at their documentation has the boolean ftp_home_dir in their example so hopefully this is just a bug? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-Working_with_SELinux-Booleans.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Red Hat's Official Response:

> On further investigation, I have found that mentioned booblean was removed on RHEL 7.3.
>
> We have already filed a bugzilla for the same, BZ:1406542
>
> https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1406542
>   It appears that , ftp users may be able to access their home directory by default on RHEL 7.3.
>
> If it doesn't work, set "ftpd_full_access" until this gets addressed in RHEL 7.3.